# show loading in libvlc flutter while rtsp stream is loading

Tags: flutter, rtsp, libvlc

i want to show loading while vlc in flutter loads rtsp stream - it takes 10 seconds and there is no feed back on screen. i am new to flutter and I wanted to know if there is any way to check when the stream is loaded and starts to play and so then I can hide loading, here is the entire code of live stream screen - where vlc player controller is playing stream

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/ScreenArguments.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';

class LiveStreamScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LiveStreamScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LiveStreamScreenState createState() => _LiveStreamScreenState();
}

class _LiveStreamScreenState extends State<LiveStreamScreen> {
final int zoomscale =1;
bool loaded = false;
  VlcPlayerController _videoPlayerController = new VlcPlayerController.network(
    "linkcomeshere",
    hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
    autoPlay: true,
    options:VlcPlayerOptions(),
  );
  bool isPlaying = true;
  bool isBuffering = true;
  String position = '';
  String duration = '';
  double sliderValue = 0.0;
  double startValue = 0.0;
  double volume = 80;
  bool playing = false;

  @override
   void initState()
  {
    log("helo2");
    super.initState();

  }
void checkIfPlaying() async
{

    bool? play = await _videoPlayerController.isPlaying();
      if (play==null) {
        print("not playing inside async");
      }
      else
        {
          playing = play;
          print("now playing inside async");
        }


}
@override
void dispose() async {
  super.dispose();
}
 _checkifplaying() async
{
  print("now inside async");
  bool? value = await _videoPlayerController.isPlaying();


  if(value == true)
    {
        print("now playing inside async");
    }
    else
    {
      print("not playing inside async");
    }
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ScreenArguments;
  _videoPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.network(
    args.data,
    hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
    autoPlay: true,
    options:VlcPlayerOptions(),

  );
  _videoPlayerController.play();
  _videoPlayerController.addListener(() {



  });
  final int zoomscale =1;
  final key = args.data2;
  String titlemain = "Screen streaming";
    
  return Scaffold(

    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body:
      SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child:
          Column
            (
              children: <Widget>[
                InteractiveViewer(

                  panEnabled: false,
                  alignPanAxis: true,
                  // Set it to false to prevent panning.
                  // boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(80),
                  minScale: 0.5,
                  maxScale: 10,
                  child: VlcPlayer(
                    controller: _videoPlayerController,
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    placeholder: const Center(child : CircularProgressIndicator()),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(titlemain, style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                ),),
                Text("Please Wait it Takes - 10 to 12 Seconds to load the lIVE Stream", style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                ),),

              ],
            ),

    ),
      ),
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The libvlc mediaplayer provides both buffering and playing events. Use these to bind your loading UI control.

Comment: Can u share a code example ?